# What was Aquaman's motivation for killing Black Manta's father?

Tags: plot-explanation, dc-extended-universe, aquaman

In *Aquaman*, after Black Manta's father was dead, Black Manta gets revenge on Aquaman.

At times I feel like Aquaman just killed Manta's father for the sake of it. So why did Aquaman kill Black Manta's father?

Comment: Aquaman didn't kill Manta's father, he just didn't save him. - __Manta__: "_Wait! Help me, he is trapped. You can't leave him like that. Please!_" __Aquaman__: "_You killed innocent people. You ask the sea for mercy._"

Comment: He was clearly pissed and upset that these guys were attacking and killing innocent sailors. That is made quite clear in the movie.

Comment: I read Black Martha in the title.. i think I'm traumatized.

Comment: Please don't roll back well-meaning grammar edits. If you object to someone's edit, please explain your objection.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, he didn't kill him, but refused to help. Black Manta's father was trapped due to a shot from his own weapon, as seen [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qb4ooMHJ5Po).

His motivation for not helping was to punish him for killing sailors previously, lack of interest or he just didn't picture him dying.

Comment: In the video you link to, Aquaman says "you got yourselves into this mess, get yourselves out of it" when he walks away and then, when asked for help answers "you killed innocent people, you
 ask the sea for mercy". So his motivation is explicitly stated.

Comment: I would say, he doesn't care about the fate, but his intention is not to kill

Comment: Yes, but your answer suggests the motivation is not clear: "was to punish him for killing sailors previously, lack of interest or just didn't picture him dying.", while the video makes it quite clear that he left them to die because he felt it was their fault they were in this situation and they deserved their fate anyway,